# Armature pose reset is not resetting mesh

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, constraints

I'm rigging a character that has mechanical parts. An Elbow/Piston joint to be exact, i've doing all the weights, rigging and now working on constraints. I've hit a snag where the mesh moves with the bones "a little bit delayed" but when on the armature I hit Alt+R to reset the pose the mesh doesn't reset with the bones and I have to hit it a couple times to fully reset the pose. I'm not sure what the cause is any help would be appreciated.

[Imgur Album](https://imgur.com/a/xdoisJa)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)